# DyanamoDB with AWS Lambda function Order by Desc Order with scan

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to create AWS Lambda function using Node.js and try to scan records from dynamodb. But it gives me records in random order I would like to fetch top 5 records which are recently added in to table. I would like to sort based on Timestamp so can get latest 5 records. Any one have an idea please help me out.

Comment: How is this related to AWS Lambda?

Answer (score 1):

dynamodb does not intend to support ordering in its scan operation. Order is supported in query operations.

To get the behavior you want you can do the following (with one caveat, see below):

Make sure that each record on your table has an attribute (let's call it `x`) which always holds the same value (does not matter which value, let's say the value is always "y")

define a global secondary index on your table. the key of that index should use `x` as the partition key (aka: "hash key") and the timestamp field as the sort key.

then you can issue a `query` action on that index. "Query results are always sorted by the sort key value" (see [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/APIReference/API_Query.html)) which is exactly what you need.

**The caveat**: this means that your index will hold all records of your table under the same partition key. This goes against best practices of dynamodb (see [Choosing the Right DynamoDB Partition Key](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/choosing-the-right-dynamodb-partition-key/)). It will not scale for large tables (more than tens of GB).